# Switch view on same URL but different method in django with rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

What is the most "pythonic" way to handle view routing on same url based on method? i don't like the solution

```
if(request.method == 'GET'):
    .......
```

is there a better way?

Comment: Use class-based views, as recommended throughout the DRF documentation.

Comment: "A ViewSet class is simply a type of class-based View, that does not provide any method handlers such as .get() or .post(), and instead provides actions such as .list() and .create()." also see: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing

Comment: seconding view sets. They'll take care of the routing along with routers

Comment: @jpic it seems that we cannot fulfill this need in function based view, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django View is the most pythonic code.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class MyView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        # <view logic>
        return HttpResponse('result')
    def post(self, request):
        # <view logic x2>
        return HttpResponse('message_post_template')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from myapp.views import MyView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^about/$', MyView.as_view(), name='view'),
]
```